# How should you write the prep stage when the source file is a .gz?

Tags: gzip, rpm

The setup macro cannot handle a .gz file. I think I should extract the source .gz file without deleting it (decompressing with gzip deletes the file normally), and then manually cd into the uncompressed directory.

I am wondering if this is a good solution.

Comment: If you mean a `.gz` without being a `.tar.gz`, then it is a single file, simply run `gzip -d` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract a directory from just a .gz file.  That would be a .tar.gz file.  The extraction of a .tar.gz file does *not* normally delete the .tar.gz file.

Comment: The source file provided came as a .gz. I'm wondering what I should do in the prep stage since %setup does not work.